# Running custom jar file with input parameters on Amazon EMR

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

So, I am trying to run the [WordCount](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html) hadoop application on Amazon EMR. I have my own data file which I uploaded to `abc bucket`. I also added the wordcount.jar file under `abc bucket`. Can anyone tell me when we create the cluster, how can we give the path to the data file and also do we need to give the output directory path as well and if yes then how can I give the output directory path?

Answer (score 0):

The data file is passed in as a parameter to the Jar, the datafile lives on the S3 bucket. The output is also a s3 bucket, in this case you can use the same bucket, just have a directory /output in the bucket and send all output to there.

https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/05/07/running-hadoop-mapreduce-jobs-on-amazon-emr/

"""Our WordCount JAR file will take the JAR’s main file, followed by the bucket name where you uploaded the input data and the output path. Note, that you only have to provide the paths, and not the precise file names. Also, make sure that no output file exists in the output path. The format for specifying input and output paths is: s3n:///path."""